# Android 'No adapter attached ; skipping layout' error Search function

Tags: java, android, firebase, layout

I have no idea how to fix this problem . I have looked all previous posts on "NO adapter attached; skipping layout" but nothing seems to work.

```
mResultList.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
                mResultList.setHasFixedSize(true);
                linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
                linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);


                mResultList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
```

This is set in another method where the firebase recycler adapter is created. Everything happens inside the fragment .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [recyclerview No adapter attached; skipping layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29141729/recyclerview-no-adapter-attached-skipping-layout)

Comment: I have tried everything any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Can you make sure that you are calling these statements from the "main" thread of fragment. (for example inside the onViewCreate() method).

```
LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
mResultList.setLayoutManager(llm);
mResultList.setAdapter( firebaseRecyclerAdapter );
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry , maybe I haven't explained it well. How can I call the mResultList.setAdapter( firebaseRecyclerAdapter ); in the OnViewCreate method  when the firebaseRecyclerAdapter is created in the onStart() method ? Thanks